# Airplane Mode is enabled automatically in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, airplane-mode

I can't use any network on my Dell inspiron 15R 5537 laptop. Airplane mode is enabled automatically and it can't be disabled.

How can I disable airplane mode permanently? Can I remove the airplane mode option by editing the Registry?

Comment: Are you entirely sure about this? Airplane mode is always on on my Windows 10 PC 24/7/365 and I can use networks just fine. Airplane mode only disables the radios.

Answer (score 2):

#### Airplane mode is enabled automatically, how do I turn it off?

> Even if your PC has a hardware switch for airplane mode, it is recommend to use the following steps instead. Some hardware switches might turn off your wireless connection in a way that lets certain apps turn the connection back on without telling you.
>
> **To Turn On or Off Airplane Mode in Action Center**
>
> 1. Open "Action Center" (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).
> 2. Click/tap on the "Airplane mode" quick action button to toggle on or off.
>
>    [image]
>
> **To Turn On or Off Airplane Mode in Network Notification Area Icon**
>
> 1. Click/tap on the "Network" icon in the taskbar notification area.
> 2. Click/tap on the "Airplane mode" button to toggle on or off.
>
>    [image]
>
> **To Turn On or Off Airplane Mode in Settings**
>
> 1. Open Settings, and click/tap on the "Network & Internet" icon.
> 2. Click/tap on "Airplane mode" on the left side, and turn on or off "Airplane mode" on the right side.
> 3. When finished, you can close Settings if you like.
>
> [image]

Source [How to Turn On or Off Airplane Mode in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/15411-airplane-mode-turn-off-windows-10-a.html)

Answer (score 2):

Power options might be turning it off:

1. Go to Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings
2. Click "Change advanced power settings".
3. Under "Wireless Adapter Settings -> Power Saving Mode" some of those options could be turning airplane mode on, and wireless off.

To prevent WiFi being shut off:

1. Open Device Manager
2. Right-click on Network Adapters -> [Wireless adapter] (something like Intel Wireless...)
3. Click Properties
4. Click Power Management tab
5. Uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"

Answer (score -1):

**Airplane mode automatically turn on and off problem window10** -

My laptop is hp-pavilion15.
I tried many solution that are writing in google but it didn't work.
Finally I got one solution by the help of **Microsoft Help**

**Open Network & Settings** -> **Status** -> **Network reset**

Becareful !!! It will reset all your known networks, virtual network adapters and so on.

If the above solution don't work, Please do the following steps.

**Open Network & Settings** -> **Airplane mode** -> **Get Help**
Tell your exact problem to Microsoft agent(Not virtual agent), they can perfectly help you.

Answer (score -1):

My laptop is a Dell latitude 7280.

Normally the laptop is always connected to wifi either at home or in the office.
Today I realised I was in airplane mode.
Whenever I disabled airplane mode in Networks it came back a few minutes later.

I Googled the problem and someone suggested the **function key with the network tower symbol** (in my case the home key, to the right of the F12).

I pressed it. This fixed the problem for me. Almost immediately I got back my list of wireless networks.

I think I'd somehow pressed that key earlier today.